# Can it be relied on a singleton instance as a shared resource?

Tags: java, spring

In a program, I am planning to use singleton hashmap, being generated in Spring IoC, as shared resourced in between different threads, but I need to make sure that this instance is not going to be regenerated ever, otherwise, I lose my cached data. Can I rely on it?

```
default-lazy-init="true"

<util:map id="sharedResource" map-class="java.util.HashMap" key-type="KeyClass" value-type="ValueClass"/>
```

Comment: Spring will initialize only one instance. Whts the issue ?

Comment: it would be singleton by default, but this wouldn't be thread safe

Comment: @Lokesh I know it is the single instance, but was it guaranteed?

Comment: @CanMingir: Yes spring gurantees singleton by default.

Comment: if multiple threads are operating on same HashMap concurrently they can result in unexpected things based on how you use, for example you read and compute and put it back, imagine two threads doing it same time

Comment: Understand that being a singleton and being thread-safe are two entirely different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring beans are singletons by default, so you are good. However, there thread safety is not guaranteed for the Hashmap used by two or more threads. You can overcome this by using ConcurrentHashMap as the map-class.

Having said that, I think this is a rudimentary caching strategy in my opinion. If it serves your purpose, then it is great. If you need more sophisticated caching strategies, suggest looking into Ehcache or Memchached.

Answer (score 0):

This generates a singleton instance **per spring application context**. You also need to make sure that all your modules share the same spring context. If another module loads its own context, you get a whole new copy of all the instances in the file, including the singleton ones.

Make sure you have a centralized place to generate and manage the life-cycle of the spring context.